# Why is Javascript's Splice function not working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

My question is quick. Here is the problem:

```
//Gets string from database in "User1|User2|User3" format
var frArray = res[0].friendRequests.split('|');

//frArray should now equal ['User1', 'User2', etc]

//data.friend is a string for the friend we are removing from requests 
//let's assume it's User1

console.log(frArray.indexOf(data.friend)); //This prints 0 

console.log(frArray); //This prints User1 which is correct

frArray = frArray.splice(frArray.indexOf(data.friend), 1);

console.log(frArray); 
//This prints User1 STILL which is not correct it should've removed it
```

I would appreciate any help, I can't figure it out. I've been stuck on this for a while. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`splice` returns an array of the elements you removed. Just remove the assignment so your variable continues to refer to the original array, which is modified in place:

```
frArray.splice(frArray.indexOf(data.friend), 1);
```

Example:

```js
const frArray = ["Jane", "Mohammed", "An"];
const removed = frArray.splice(0, 1);
console.log(`removed: ${JSON.stringify(removed)}`);
console.log(`frArray: ${JSON.stringify(frArray)}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation of [`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

> The splice() method changes the contents of an array by removing or
>   replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements in place.

And it [returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Return_value):

> An array containing the deleted elements. If only one element is
>   removed, an array of one element is returned. If no elements are
>   removed, an empty array is returned.

So `splice` **mutates** the **original** array and returns the `removed elements`.

In your code you have: `frArray = frArray.splice(frArray.indexOf(data.friend), 1);`

Where you are **assigning** the result of `splice` to your `frArray` instead of just executing the `splice` and then continue to use your original (now mutated array):

```
var frArray = res[0].friendRequests.split('|');      

frArray.splice(frArray.indexOf(data.friend), 1); // <-- no assignment

console.log(frArray);
```